# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I suddenly have a problem with my flutter app. For some reason, I can't run any of my flutter files. Every time I try to run any of my flutter projects it keeps giving me an error message.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_appavailability:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr} using transform PlatformAttrTransform
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/wooyoung/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar (No such file or directory)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with the -the-info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

So, I made a new flutter app to test if it was just a problem in my project. But it gave me an error again.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
 Output:  W/ziparchive(29306): Unable to open '/Users/wooyoung/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar': No such file or directory
 error: failed to open APK: I/O error.

 Command:
/Users/wooyoung/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/7624077eb86a2607fdc7dac1f332a5dd/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
         /Users/wooyoung/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
         --manifest\
         /Users/wooyoung/Flutter/FlutterProjects/Experiment/j/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
  -o\
         /Users/wooyoung/Flutter/FlutterProjects/Experiment/j/build/app/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
         -R\
         @/Users/wooyoung/Flutter/FlutterProjects/Experiment/j/build/app/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
         --auto-add-overlay\
         --java\
         /Users/wooyoung/Flutter/FlutterProjects/Experiment/j/build/app/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
         --custom-package\
         com.example.j\
         -0\
         apk\
         --no-version-vectors
    Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you run it on iOS simulator?

Comment: Yes, It's fine on my iOS simulator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that necessary Android 27 API's are missing in your Android sdk directory. go to `~/library/android/sdk/tools/bin` and run `sdkmanager --list` to check if you have `platform-tools` and `platforms;android-27` installed. If not, then you can install them by running `sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-27"`

If you have Android Studio, then you can install them via Android Studio's GUI, too.

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot. But It's not working even after I have downloaded the API.

Comment: Could you please try again after running `sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"` as well?

Comment: In my terminal?

Comment: Yes, in your terminal and by changing to same directory with `cd ~/library/android/sdk/tools/bin`

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 0):

open file menu---> project structure--->project settings--->project

check your project SDK

also check >>>project structure--->platform settings--->sdks

give same SDK and click ok

try to run project

Answer (score 0):

No need to make changes except your main.dart page code on loading new project in android studio(If you configured properly)
copy paste https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flutter/flutter_creating_simple_application_in_android_studio.htm from provided url and run main.dart all problem will be solved

Answer (score -1):

You should leave the default splash screen because it takes time to load the program !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>

   <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
<!--     <item>
       <bitmap
           android:gravity="center"
           android:src="@mipmap/launch_image"/>
   </item> -->
</layer-list>
```