# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. in flutter

Tags: flutter-dependencies

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. in flutter

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
>     Output:  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\crossplatform\scoodent\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:101: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

Comment: See [ask] and make sure you take the [tour]. [Edit] this question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244959/failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-in-flutter#

Comment: check your SDK version, try up the version.