# Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:parseDebugLocalResources

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, error-handling

I get this error when I want to run "flutter" project from my phone with "visual studio code".

how can i solve it?

**PROBLEM**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar.
> > C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FAILURE: Build failed with an exception in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244959/failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

When the.jar file mentioned above was overlooked, this issue would arise. You must take a number of actions in order to resolve this issue.

step 1: `Android Studio > SDK Manager > SDK Platforms`

[Android Studio SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKw2Z.png)

step 2: `Select only Android 11.0(R) - API Level 30`
(Uncheck other API Levels to Uninstall other API Levels temporary. Special API Level 31, 33)
`Apply & Ok`

step 3: `flutter clean`

step 4: `cd android`

step 5: `./gradlew clean`

step 6: `./gradlew build` ->
*FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.*

step 7: `./gradlew --stacktrace` ->
*BUILD SUCCESSFUL*

step 8: `flutter run`

**Ensure that your development device is connected to a more reliable internet connection.**

Answer (score 0):

you probably have to check if the version of the **jdk** you use is installed correctly